# How to forward to https with htaccess without redirect loops

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to add a rule to have users who access the site use https. I add this code (right before the closing IfModule tag) and get a redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How do I adjust my file to eliminate any unnecessary redirects?

Comment: Yes, it is for a forum. The first part I added to make URLs "cleaner", which has been working well.

Comment: What is your Apache version? Is there a proxy in front of Apache?

Comment: It's a shared host using Apache 2.2.31-2 with Cloudflare enabled for the domain. I don't think there's a proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /f/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Equivalent PHP code for `http->https`:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] != 'https'){
    header("Location: https://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, however I have an issue with some resources loading. I checked the software and it has a provision that uses this line for https. Is there a way to convert your method to a header in php?
    header("Location: https://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

Comment: Effectively it is same thing.

Comment: If I use that header in php, I also get the redirect loop. Is there a way I can convert and add your line "RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https" to a php header?

Comment: I am not a PHP programmer but I've suggested some PHP code in answer for that redirection

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much, you are a master and the bee's knees!